ApiSetMap does not contain mapping for certain API sets
I have been writing a manual map injector for Windows 10 (C++). While writing the import resolution segment of my injector, I had learned about the ApiSetMap field of the PEB. While I was studying the use and fields of this map, I had noticed that not Windows\System32\ApiSetSchema.dll, nor any of the extensions of the ApiSetMap listed in the registry, contained the string "api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0", which is an API set that Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll forwards to. Does anybody know for a fact how the host of API sets like this are resolved?
I had written a separate program that parsed the ApiSetMap and printed out namespace entries, specifically, the names of the API sets and the names of their host modules so that I could get a better visualization of the map than dumping the strings, and so that I could get used to the data layout of the ApiSetMap. In doing this, I noticed that api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0, the API set forwarded to by Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll, which is not in the ApiSetMap, could be mapped correctly to Windows\SysWOW64\kernelbase.dll by simply truncating the last 2 characters of the API set name (and the .dll if its there). Normally id assume that this was a product of luck, but I noticed that the API_SET_NAMESPACE_ENTRY struct has a member that specifies the size, in bytes, of the API set name with these exact truncations. This leads me to believe that Windows is handling the resolution of various API sets the same way to minimize the size of ApiSetMap. And I know that kernelbase.dll is the correct host for api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0, because when I checked the locations at which imported forwarders from kernel32.dll to api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0 were called, they led to functions in kernelbase.dll (obviously I made this observation when the DLL was loaded via LoadLibrary). If anybody knows why this API set is not in the ApiSetMap or if my method of resolving it is the same as the Windows Image Loader, I would greatly appreciate an answer!

We cannot help you without a minimal reproducible example (MRE) in source code.  What you should do now is to make sure your code stores ALL return values (from API calls) so you can do a line-by-line debug session and check those return values for errors. Then if you still have issues, make the MRE and ask ONE detailed question about the error you don't understand and include debugging details.

The link you provided says the last part of the name (from last hyphen onwards) is insignificant. I guess you could test this by calling LoadLibrary with bogus last name part.

if you view that dll name begin from "API-" or EXT-" use LoadLibraryExW + LdrGetProcedureAddress (or GetProcAddress) for get actual address of api
